# Multiple ID's for getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

See this code:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFFP03OMYA94

I've got two buttons (or even more). When I click on the first button, it should display the first *div*. When I click on the second button, it should display the other *div*.
This is only a snippet of my problem. I want to achieve, that when I click on a button, then it should open the *div* with the passed ID. Normally I have an unique ID, so I could also save the ID like this:

```
<div id="myModal+${person.id}" class="modal">
```

My problem is: How can I pass the ID to my javaScript and open the specific *div* for the passed ID?

Comment: use data attributes

Comment: could you maybe send a link as an example?

Comment: As for the title of the question - ["*Multiple ID's*" in a single HTML document are not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme). As mentioned by *@Vishnu*, use  [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store this ID in a `data-*` attribute, like this:

```js
// Here, I used a class for the buttons, since there are multiple ones
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('myBtn'),
    // These variables will hold the currently open modal and close button
    modal, closeBtn;

// For each button
for(var i=0; i<btns.length; i++) {
    // On click
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      // Get the modal ID
      var modalId = this.getAttribute('data-modal');
      // Retrieve the corresponding modal
      modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
      // Retrieve the close button
      closeBtn = modal.querySelector('.close');
      // Show the modal
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }, false);
}

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // If we clicked on the backdrop or the close button
    if (event.target == modal || event.target == closeBtn) {
        // Hide the modal
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}, false);
```

```css
.modal{display:none;position:fixed;z-index:1;padding-top:100px;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;background-color:#000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4)}.modal-content{background-color:#fefefe;margin:auto;padding:20px;border:1px solid #888;width:80%}.close{color:#aaa;float:right;font-size:28px;font-weight:700}.close:focus,.close:hover{color:#000;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<button class="myBtn" data-modal="myModalA">Open Modal A</button>
<div id="myModalA" class="modal"><div class="modal-content"><span class="close">&times;</span><p>This is myModalA</p></div></div>

<button class="myBtn" data-modal="myModalB">Open Modal B</button>
<div id="myModalB" class="modal"><div class="modal-content"><span class="close">&times;</span><p>This is myModalB</p></div></div>

<button class="myBtn" data-modal="myModalC">Open Modal C</button>
<div id="myModalC" class="modal"><div class="modal-content"><span class="close">&times;</span><p>This is myModalC</p></div></div>

<button class="myBtn" data-modal="myModalD">Open Modal D</button>
<div id="myModalD" class="modal"><div class="modal-content"><span class="close">&times;</span><p>This is myModalD</p></div></div>
```